# Strategy or dessign pattern to restrict creation of objects

Tags: java, design-patterns, restriction

Let´s say I have implemented the class `Dog`:

```
public class Dog {
    private String breed;
    private Set<Colour> colours;
}
```

I have also implemented a function to parse information about available dogs from an external file. Afterwards, I have a collection of `Dog` objects (e.g. doberman, chihuahua, husky, golden). Within each dog, there is the name of the breed and a set of available colours for each breed (e.g. for golden: yellow, cinamon, white).

Moreover, I want to let the user create `House` objects. Each `House` might contain a `Dog` as an attribute, but I want to restrict the options, so the user must be able to create only dogs specified within my collection. The user must not be able to create a "yorkshire" or a "beagle", nor green or blue chihuahuas.

Which strategy or dessign pattern should I use?

Extra: I am developing a library (or framework, it is not clear yet). My task is to offer an API, a bunch of functions the user might need.

Answer (score 3):

I would separate the concepts of the `Breed` and the actual `Dog`. It's the `Breed`'s responsibility to know of the allowed `Colour`s, While the `Dog`'s constructor must make sure that the breed and colour match.

You can make `Breed` an enum to make sure only dogs of the breeds you know are created:

```
public enum Breed {

    MYBREED(Color.BLACK, Color.GRAY),
    MYOTHERBREED(Color.GRAY);

    private List<Color> colors = new ArrayList<Color>();

    private Breed(Color...colors) {
        for(Color color: colors) {
            this.colors.add(color);
        }
    }

    public List<Color> getAllowedColors() {
        return colors;
    }

}
```

The downside of using java enums is that you can't generate them dynamically at runtime. In this case you'd have to replace it by some handcrafed solution, e.g. using the [multiton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern).

And then the `Dog`-class can use it:

```
public class Dog {

    private Breed breed;
    private Color color;

    public Dog(Breed breed, Color color) {
        if(!breed.getAllowedColors().contains(color)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(breed + " must not be of color " + color);
        }
        this.breed = breed;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Breed getBreed() {
        return breed;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    // No setters for breed and color because they cannot change during a dog's lifetime

      //... some more things a dog can do

}
```

Comment: is it possible to generate enums at runtime? I must import the information on available breeds and colours from an external file. This file might change every now and then.